# Exist vector field having only finitely many zeros, all lying in open set of compact connected manifold?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

Let $U$ be any open set on the compact connected manifold $X$. Does there exist a vector field having only finitely many zeros, all of which lie in $U$?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This depends of the topology of $U$, if a vector field have finitely many zeros, their number are related to the Euler characteristic see

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Hopf_theorem

So you have to check that the Euler characteristic of the complement of $U$ (which is a manifold with boundary) is zero.

Comment: The Poincaré–Hopf theorem only applies to a vector field on $U$ if the vector field is everywhere outward-pointing on $\partial U$, as the Wikipedia article explains. Since the problem didn't specify anything about the values of the vector field on $\partial U$, the Euler characteristic is not an obstruction. (See my answer below.)

Answer (score 5):

This is always possible. Start with a vector field on $X$ that has only finitely many zeros, and then apply a diffeomorphism of $X$ that takes all of the zeros into $U$. (For any one of the zeros, you can find a diffeomorphism of $X$ that takes it to a point in $U$; and if you've already put some of the zeros in $U$, you can arrange that the diffeomorphism doesn't move those points.)

Comment: This argument is not true. Suppose that you have constructed $L$. It satisfies the Poincare formula for $L$. Let $x\in U$, you can find a small neighborhood $V$ of $x$ such that the field point outward on  $X-V$, so you can apply Poincare on the restriction of $L$ to $X-V$. This implies the euler characteristic of $X$ is the euler characteristic of $X-V$.

Comment: @TsemoAristide: I don't understand your claim that "you can find a small neighborhood $V$ of $x$ such that the field points outward on $X - V$." Depending on the index of the vector field at $x$, this might or might not be possible.

Comment: It always possible, if $x$ is not a zero.